# quickbooks api to add a payment against an invoice with RubyRails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quickbooks, qbxml

I am trying to mark an invoice mark as paid and as per my understanding I have to add a payment against the invoice. I am using **qbwc gem** and it is using **qbxml v.13**.
I have found out few examples of creating the payment object here https://community-intuit.force.com/developer/s/article/QBO-REST-Apply-payments-to-invoice but the qbxml tag for creating payment is not clear to me.

Here are few xml tags that I have found in OSR ReceivePaymentAddRq, ItemPaymentAddRq etc

But I am still not sure how to create the payment object and which xml tags should be used and help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal qbXML example looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="10.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <ReceivePaymentAddRq>
            <ReceivePaymentAdd>
                <CustomerRef>
                    <ListID>F230000-1196864585</ListID>
                    <!--<FullName>Keith Palmer</FullName>--> <!-- You can specify either ListID or FullName -->
                </CustomerRef>

                <TxnDate>2007-12-14</TxnDate>
                <RefNumber>00612361</RefNumber>
                <TotalAmount>195.00</TotalAmount>

                <!-- Specify the Invoice TxnID here, or see below for auto-apply... -->
                <AppliedToTxnAdd>
                    <TxnID>12006-1196864828</TxnID>
                    <PaymentAmount>195.00</PaymentAmount>
                </AppliedToTxnAdd>
    
                <!-- If you don't want to apply payments manually to a particular transaction, use <IsAutoApply>true</IsAutoApply> -->
                <!--   instead of the <AppliedToTxn> node. QuickBooks will make it's best guess how to apply the payment. -->
            </ReceivePaymentAdd>
        </ReceivePaymentAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create one payment for few invoices for different customers?

Comment: @Schroet  I'm not sure I'm really understanding your question here... how would you receive a single payment from multiple customers at once?  I can't think of a way in real-life where e.g. someone can write you a _single check_ that comes out of _two bank accounts at once_. Or a _single credit card payment_ that actually charges _two credit cards_. That's not possible in the real world, right...?